# Is it worth running memcache on my server?

Tags: php, ubuntu, memcached, ram

This may seem like a newbie-ish question but I couldn't find an answer for this on google.

I have a server with 128mb of ram. I was wondering if installing memcache will help reduce serverload, say I sacrifice 5-10mb of ram to memcache. Is this even worth it? And if it is, how would I limit memcache to 5-10mb of ram?

Comment: 128MB? you've got to be kidding. These days you can't find a computer with less than 2-4GB RAM

Comment: @mvp true, but this is just a startup vps. i might get a better one but right now this is what i have to deal with.

Comment: are you running apache or something else?

Comment: @mvp apache. if you are interested in how much memory my server uses under normal usage, its about 70-90mb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should replace apache with nginx first. This will allow you to reduce memory usage, probably even below 64MB, and also server load.

Then, you can allocate up to 60MB remaining memory to memcached, and it should help to reduce load even further.

Comment: umm... going down from apache to nginx? i mean i have several preinstalled mods and i use htaccess. but i see your point. and in other words, 5-20mb of memcache makes no difference

Comment: nginx has a lot of almost drop-in replacement modules for apache users http://wiki.nginx.org/ModuleComparisonMatrix

Comment: Could try lighttpd, will require rewriting your .htaccess files but should use some less memory as well.

Comment: ok mvp. ive marked this as answer and will try out your solution. thanks!